# unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql

This page has a variable (aucname2) passed to it, it should then use that as the value for the sql statement.  But it keeps telling me that value is being used as the column and then of course telling me that column doesn't exist

```
<?php 
    $auc = $_GET['aucname2'];
    $db_name = "auctionfinal";
    $table_name = "auctions";
    $connection = @mysql_connect("auctionfinal.db.6084638.hostedresource.com","xxxxx", "xxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    $db = @mysql_select_db($db_name, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE `aucname` = $auc";
    $result = @mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $aucname3 = $row['aucname'];
            $seller = $row['seller'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $start = $row['start'];
            $end = $row['end'];
            $nbids = $row['nbids'];
            $category = $row['category'];
            $link = "pagename.php?aucname=$aucname";

            $display_block = "Auction Name - $aucname3 &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Seller - $seller &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Price - $price &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Start Date - $start </br>
            End Date - $end &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            # bids - $nbids &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            Category - $category
            <p> ------------------ </p>";

       }
       echo "$display_block";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what an incredible mess :)

Comment: Still kind of sucks, but it is a bit better...

Comment: Good rule of thumb... if your calling a database query, and generating HTML in the same block of code, your doing something HORRIBLY HORRIBLY wrong.  Read up on MVC for the love of GOD!

Comment: LOL thank you.  I know it is a mess.  It isn't going to be used in real life - I just need the thing to work which it is now!

Comment: @Zoidberg. I love your pedagogical approach :)

Answer (score 7):

Change this line:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE aucname = $auc";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE aucname = '$auc'";
```

Since `$auc` is a string, it needs to be enclosed in quotes, otherwise MySQL will try to look for the value of that variable as a column name.

Also, you should probably use `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$auc` first because otherwise you will be vulnerable to SQL injection.